# How to retrieve user information from recent version of Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm new to Hyperledger Fabric. In the current version of Hyperledger Fabric, in chaincode.go I can't find the function called ReadCertAttributes. Is there any way to get attributes?

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Hypeledger Fabric 1.0.0 you can use [`GetCreator`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L169) method of [`ChaincodeStubInterface`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go#L42) to obtain clients certificate, e.g.:

```
// GetCreator returns `SignatureHeader.Creator` (e.g. an identity)
// of the `SignedProposal`. This is the identity of the agent (or user)
// submitting the transaction.
GetCreator() ([]byte, error)
```

For example you can do something similar to:

```
func (*smartContract) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    fmt.Println("Invoke")

    // GetCreator returns marshaled serialized identity of the client
    serializedID, _ := stub.GetCreator()

    sId := &msp.SerializedIdentity{}
    err := proto.Unmarshal(serializedID, sId)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Could not deserialize a SerializedIdentity, err %s", err))
    }

    bl, _ := pem.Decode(sId.IdBytes)
    if bl == nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to decode PEM structure"))
    }
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(bl.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to parse certificate %s", err))
    }

    // Do whatever you need with certificate

    return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Artem Barger : Can you please attach the full source of the above code?

Comment: @AmanC, well the fact is that I do not have a full source code, since wrote in on the spot to answer your question. Please consider to look on following library: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/core/chaincode/lib/cid its should help you to extract information from certificate and work with it more easily

Comment: is it feasible to get user role as well?

Comment: `serializedID.Subject.CommonName` is a name (Jim, Barry in fabric-sample)

Comment: @ArtemBarger Page not found