# enroll multiple users to an organization and control policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric. I read its documentation and followed the [test network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html) they provided on their website

I have the network up and running can any one help advising me how to add multiple users to  an organization and control the policy for each user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A [sample function](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/49749c65846b2d03e0b646150297532bc2543cc6/test-application/javascript/CAUtil.js#L53) for enrolling users using the Fabric CA is available in fabric samples. You may write an Express server over this function to enroll many users as required. A [sample REST server](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/bc72f3e3a681eeca12dc4858d07e938244da825f/balance-transfer/app/helper.js#L64) for enrolling users was there in the earlier versions of fabric-samples, but that was removed. But you can still refer the old one to write a similar REST server using the new fabric-ca-client.

The details of a user submitting the transaction can be accessed in the chaincode using the [ClientIdentity](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-node/release-2.1/api/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html) class. Policies can be written in chaincode using this information(like MSPID of client, attributes of client etc.). Also it's possible to [get the X.509 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786023/how-to-retrieve-user-information-from-recent-version-of-hyperledger-fabric) of the transaction sender in the chaincode and write rules based on it.